# Pushing Blog Post to Twitter & Facebook (with Customization)

Tags: facebook, drupal, twitter, blogs

I'm curious if there is a module or available starting point to solve for the following requirement.

When an administrator writes and publishes a blog post I want the ability to push that post automatically (and optionally) to both Facebook and Twitter *with one caveat*

I want to be able to customize the Facebook and Twitter post to have custom content and allow for the unique attributes of each channel.  Ie have a thumbnail image for the Facebook post, change the title of the Twitter post to include #hashtags and such.

Does anyone know of an existing module or customization that would allow for this or provide a head start on building out this customization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well there's the twitter module: http://drupal.org/project/twitter and also the 'Simple Facebook Wall Post': http://drupal.org/project/simple_fbwall. I haven't used either of these myself yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try these for automatic publishing. Make a rule for sending emails.
https://drupal.org/project/facebook_rules

https://drupal.org/project/facebook_page_rules

This module gives a checkbox to tweet automatically.

https://drupal.org/project/twitter